# playlist load take too much time and my bot get disconnected (yt-dl and discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl, ytdl

I have a strange problem with my bot made with discord.py and youtube-dl, when I load a small playlist the bot works perfectly, when instead I load a long playlist, like 100 songs, the bot has to download them all and then start them , I think the time used to download the songs is seen as inactivity and then the bot disconnects, however it does not disconnect from the channel on discord, only code side it disconnects, how can i solve?

This is my join function:

```
@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("Non sei in un canale non so dove andare")
    else:
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        self.is_connected = True
```

This is my play function:

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await self.join(ctx)
    if self.is_connected:
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            #print(info)
        titleartist = ''
        duration = ''
        #print("INFO:  " + str(info))
        if info.get('_type') == 'playlist':
            temp_url = ' '
            for x in info.get('entries'):
                #print("x:  " + str(x))
                temp_url = x['formats'][0]['url']
                if 'title' in x.keys():
                    titleartist = x['title']
                if 'duration' in x.keys():
                    duration = x['duration']
                self.queue.append(temp_url)
                self.songsinfo.append([temp_url, titleartist, duration])
            if not self.playing:
                self.currentsonginfo = self.songsinfo.pop(0)
                temp_song = self.queue.pop(0)
                vc = ctx.voice_client
                source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(temp_song, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                self.playing = True
                time.sleep(2)
                vc.play(source, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.next_song(ctx, vc, temp_url), self.client.loop))
        else:
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            if 'title' in info.keys():
                titleartist = info['title']
            if 'duration' in info.keys():
                duration = info['duration']
            if self.playing:
                self.queue.append(url2)
                self.songsinfo.append([url2, titleartist, duration])
                self.index += 1
                if not self.skipped:
                    await ctx.send("Musica Aggiunta alla Coda")
                else:
                    self.skipped = False
            else:
                self.currentsonginfo = [url2, titleartist, duration]
                vc = ctx.voice_client
                source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                self.playing = True
                time.sleep(2)
                vc.play(source, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.next_song(ctx, vc, url2), self.client.loop))
```

This is the error I get:

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\mymusic.py", line 72, in play
    vc.play(source, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.next_song(ctx, vc, temp_url), self.client.loop))
  File "C:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 555, in play
    raise ClientException('Not connected to voice.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Not connected to voice.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.
```

Answer (score 0):

> the bot has to download them all and then start them

**1.** Don't download the tracks, stream the raw URL (The argument for the command line is --get-url) (You say you are downloading but the code does not do that it extracts raw URL?)

**2.** I've noticed that YT-DL seems to be slower now. I use a new library called [YT-DLP](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) It is way faster than YT-DL and I am able to parse through an entire playlist of 200 songs in less than 5 seconds. (not downloading them of course.)

**3.** Instead of parsing a whole playlist and extracting raw URLs all at once, extract just the regular URL then when it's time for that song to play from the queue, extract the raw URL and then, play it.

Comment: ty for answer, I read about this ytdlp but didn't find tutorial about it

Comment: btw I thought download=False was enough to not download it...